# react:Unable to get id of NavDropdown using onclick event

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am trying to get the id of NavDropdown and trying to set new value to show  in react js using onclick event.
I have tried following code but its not working.

```
        <NavDropdown title="Learn" id='Learn'
          onMouseEnter = { this.handleOpen }
          onMouseLeave = { this.handleClose }
          show={this.state.isOpen}
           >

        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>

     <NavDropdown title="API"
       onMouseEnter = { this.handleOpen }
       onMouseLeave = { this.handleClose }
       show= {this.state.isOpen} 
       id='API'
      >
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>

      constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = { isOpen:false }
      this.handleOpen = this.handleOpen.bind(this);
      this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);

      }
       handleOpen(event) {
       document.getElementById(event.target.id).show=true;
      }
       handleClose(event){
       document.getElementById(event.target.id).show=false;
      }
```

Comment: try using `event.currentTarget.id`

Comment: hi @elvis-ferns still getting error ''Cannot set property 'show' of null ''

Comment: show property is not on underlying DOM element. Its on the component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `this.setState` instead an`event.target.id` with `show` property.

```
 handleOpen() {
   this.setState({isOpen: true});
  }
 handleClose(){
   this.setState({isOpen: false});
 }
```